# TypeORM createConnection takes long time

Tags: lambda, typeorm

We have a lambda function running for multi-tenants, and we noticed from time to time the `createConnection` call takes 3-4 seconds. Could that be related to typeorm having to parse all entity definitions when creating new connections (which doesn't make sense to me) or there are other reasons that could make it to take such a long time?

Comment: Does the times that it doesn't take 3-4 seconds for createConnection to start is it when the connection is already up?

Comment: No, in the case when it didn't take 3-4 seconds the connection wasn't up, but when the connection was already up it always took just a few hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: did u get any solution to this?